# Issue using "AndroidSwipeLayout" Library of "daimajia" for version above 4.4 (kitkat)- BackView Swipe more from the right side

Tags: android, android-layout

I've using AndroidSwipeLayout Library from "daimajia" [Android Swipe Layout](https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidSwipeLayout)

It's working fine although for version above 4.4 Kitkat. The backview of the swipe layout is swipe more from the right side..

plz refer to the attached images both for below 4.4 kitkat and above version

> Android Swipe Layout Works Perfectly for Android Ver. 4.2 (jellybean) below Kitkat

[image: Android Swipe Layout Works Perfectly for Android Ver. 4.2 (jellybean) below Kitkat]

> Android Swipe Layout - backview slides more from right for Android ver. 4.4 Kitkat and above

[image: Android Swipe Layout - backview slides more from right for Android ver. 4.4 Kitkat and above]

Comment: What is your question? I guess you should create an issue on his repo.

Comment: yes ... for ver. 4.4 and above the backview positioning is not proper...

Comment: It's an open source library, so if it doesn't work the way you want, you read the code, and modify to do what you want, programming is not just about getting a bunch of libs together...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i've solve the issue ...

this is my xml for swipelayout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<com.synsoft.foodjini.swipelib.SwipeLayout         xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:swipe="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
     android:id="@+id/swipe"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     swipe:leftEdgeSwipeOffset="0dp"
     swipe:rightEdgeSwipeOffset="0dp"
     swipe:show_mode="lay_down"
     android:background="@color/colorPrimary">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/cart.item.back"
    android:layout_width="600px"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:tag="Bottom3"
    android:weightSum="10"
    android:paddingLeft="6dp"
    android:paddingRight="6dp"
    android:paddingTop="12dp"
    android:paddingBottom="12dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/edit"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/cart_main_item_edit_ico"/>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/delete"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/cart_main_item_delete_ico"/>

</LinearLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/cart.item.front"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="6dp"
    android:paddingRight="6dp"
    android:paddingTop="12dp"
    android:paddingBottom="12dp"
    android:background="@android:color/white">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/quantities"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="2"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="normal"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/cart.item.names"
        android:layout_width="220dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="X Item Name Lorem Ipsum"
        android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/quantities"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="normal"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/cart.item.portions"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="small"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/cart.item.names"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/cart.item.names"
        android:textSize="13sp"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textStyle="normal"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/cart.item.prices"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="20.00"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/cart_item_rupee_ico"
        android:drawablePadding="6dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/cart.item.names"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="normal"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/cart.item.divider1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/cart_main_item_sap"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/cart.item.names"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/cart.item.names"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_below="@+id/cart.item.divider1"
        android:id="@+id/cart.item.addons.tag"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="12dp">

    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/cart_main_item_sap"
        android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/cart.item.addons.tag"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/cart.item.names"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

> what i've done is matches the background of the SwipeLayout
>   (parentlayout) and back view (swipeview) 
>   android:background="@color/colorPrimary"..  so that if backview
>   positioning is improper than the view doesn't seems so asymetric

Also change the show_mode of the SwipeLayout to lay_down
and background of the frontview to white

hence this skip the issue found on kitkat and higher version.

although its not the proper solution.. in the future i have to study the lib and try to find why positioning is improper for kitkat n above

[image]

Answer (score 7):

I've made some research and find out that something is wrong with drag distance. For now I've figured out work around. This cause strange jump on animation but in the end backview will go to proper position. I'll try to find better solution.

In class "SwipeLayout" we need to modify "open" method:

```
public void open(boolean smooth, boolean notify) {
    View surface = getSurfaceView(), bottom = getCurrentBottomView();
    if (surface == null) {
        return;
    }
    int dx, dy;
    Rect rect = computeSurfaceLayoutArea(true);
    // if (smooth) {
    // mDragHelper.smoothSlideViewTo(surface, rect.left, rect.top);
    // } else {
    dx = rect.left - surface.getLeft();
    dy = rect.top - surface.getTop();
    surface.layout(rect.left, rect.top, rect.right, rect.bottom);
    if (getShowMode() == ShowMode.PullOut) {
        Rect bRect = computeBottomLayoutAreaViaSurface(ShowMode.PullOut, rect);
        if (bottom != null) {
            bottom.layout(bRect.left, bRect.top, bRect.right, bRect.bottom);
        }
    }
    if (notify) {
        dispatchRevealEvent(rect.left, rect.top, rect.right, rect.bottom);
        dispatchSwipeEvent(rect.left, rect.top, dx, dy);
    } else {
        safeBottomView();
    }
    // }
    invalidate();
}
```

Comment: i really appreciate your efforts :-) .... I'll wait for your better solution.. although this helps .. but some time its positioning is improper whats the real problem is.. it remains same

Comment: Unfortunately I'am quite busy now, so I won't work on this library soon. Maybe you'd like to check this library:
https://github.com/baoyongzhang/SwipeMenuListView

This swipe is a little harder to use, and you have to define your swipe buttons in code, but it works : )

Comment: i've already use this lib initially..the problem found in this is that back-view is restricted & we'r not allow to attach our layout to back-view (swipe menu). you are only allow to create using SwipeMenuCreator with limited option.... i've also try to customize the SwipeMenuCreator or other java class acc to my need .. allow to attach layout for back-view (swipe menu) .. but overall found the issue... the better solution found is to switch to other lib or our own method...

Comment: although i really appreciate your concern with this .. thanks